# media module for drupal 6

Tags: 7, media

I only see a Drupal 7 version for the [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) module. On usage statistics I do see some Drupal 6 users using this module.

Is there anyway I can use this module with my drupal 6 install

How difficult would it be to port this module to Drupal 6 for a developer very experienced with Drupal 6 and somewhat with 7.

Is there any initiative to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is/was a development effort underway to backport the module to Drupal 6.

You can find the dev version (media 6.x-1.x-dev) [here](http://drupal.org/node/356730), but it hasn't been touched since February 2011.

The [issue queue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/media?text=&status=Open&priorities=All&categories=All&version=356730&component=All) is also empty so it doesn't look like there's a lot going on with it. It might give you a place to start coding it yourself though

Comment: You beat me to it!